# postman url replaces env. variables incorrectly in canary v8.7.0

Tags: postman

I use postman canary v8.7.0. I use environment variables as placeholders for the base URL, but for some reason, the last one, always ends up with extra %0A, and ruins the request. any idea why?
environment variables:
[image: environment vars + interpreted URL down left]
request screen:
[image]

and in the console, this is what comes out:
[image]

Comment: Do you have an extra white space at the end of the variable value? Can you expand the images of the app, it's tough to see what's happening with a zoomed in section.

Comment: no white spaces. I updated the pictures, I hope I got your meaning

Comment: On the environment quick view, can you hover over the value and press the pencil icon, just to ensure that nothing have been copy/pasted on the end of `videos`. Did you manually type the variable or paste it in from a text editor that may have added a hidden character. Is it always the last one?

Comment: manually typed. I checked with the pencil as you said, it's as expected. 
and the other second part of the baseurl({{authAPI}}, referenced in the picture above) doesn't cause the same problem, but when it happens, its always the last one, {{videoAPI}}

Comment: Could you add another variable in the list as the last one and see if that then makes the other one work?

Comment: I did, but no, it stays with the $0A instead...
by the way, it seams like other variables work just fine, only problem is with this videoAPI variable

Answer (score 0):

This is the new line character. Just go to the window where you edit all variables (not to the view where you only edit current value of a variable. It does not show you the new line character there).

Then you will be able to see the newline character at the end of the string represented by a newline symbol. You can delete it from there.